# How can I detect which modules depend on which modules in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, refactoring, code-analysis

What tools can determine which modules have methods that are calling methods from other modules in Ruby?

**Background:** I'm partway through breaking a 808 line module into smaller modules, having created 12-submodules. However, some of the methods in one of the modules are calling methods in another sub-module. This may or may not be ok, depending on whether the module of the called method is meant to be common functionality.

```
module DisplayStatistics1
  def display_statistics_1_foo
    calculate_statistics_foo # call a method that's in CalculateStatistics - this is ok
    display_statistics_2_bar # call a method that's in DisplayStatistics2 - this is bad
  end

  # other methods omitted
end

# modules DisplayStatistics2 and CalculateStatistics omitted

class ExampleClass
  include DisplayStatistics1
  include DisplayStatistics2
  include CalculateStatistics
end
```

Ideally the analysis tool would show that `DisplayStatistics1` has dependencies on `DisplayStatistics2` as well as on `CalculateStatistics`.

**Update:** Maybe I shouldn't have done it this way - maybe I should have split them up into classes instead. That way, I'd have known for sure what depended on what!

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not aware of a static analysis tool for Ruby, the one that seems closest to what you want is [rubyprof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/). This can generate a callgraph in many formats, including an HTML tree and even a GraphViz box-and-line plot.